# How to generate an ICS (ical) file with php

Tags: php, calendar, google-calendar-api

I want to generate an ics file from my event table in php.
So after downloading this file we can use this in my google calendar

Comment: Welcome to stack we deal in questions this appears to be a statement.   Did you forget to add your code and any issues you are having with it?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Look up the format of an ICAL file and write a file in that format with the data in your table. Its just a text file afterall

Comment: Okay thanks, Undestood

Answer (score 4):

Try this https://icalendar.org/php-library.html

a `php` lib that helps you generate `ical` files.

Comment: i want without lib.  i also want to delete event when we delete some event from our db and also generate new ics file.

Comment: good luck then..

Comment: This library good also https://github.com/spatie/calendar-links